# Filters on Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have 3 Time Series Charts (A,B,C) on a Page. I have 2 filters on the same page (X,Y). I want X to affect A. And Y to affect all three charts. How do I do this? Grouping doesn't work as it gets X to affect all charts or Y to not affect A.

Comment: [As of REVISION 1] **Needs details**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Expected output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 3) An attempt at solving the issue (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score -1):

You can surely achieve what you want with grouping.

Just group control X with chart A, and keep charts B and C and control Y ungrouped.

This way, control X will affect only chart A, and control Y will affect all charts.  I just tested here and it works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

You can have duplicated data sets and have the charts created using those data sets.

Along with "blending the data" you can achieve- x >> A and Y>> B,C